# update our SSO from JASIG cas 3.4.2 to cas 3.4.10

Tags: oauth, single-sign-on, updates, cas, jasig

we currently running JASIG CAS 3.4.2 with JBOSS TreeCache on debian linux and would like to update to 3.4.10. (to support OAuth)

It's obviously more complicated than just turning the cas-server-core version in pom.xml to 3.4.10.

We really would like to find a guide in the net, how to upgrade and what parts of the flow needs to get adjusted.

We would really rather like to **adjust the current spring configuration to fit for 3.4.10,** than download a 3.4.10 sample configuration and customize this.

We have a customized loginView.ftl so we have to adjust the hidden input tags  like described here: 
https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/Upgrading

But seems like we have to change something in loginflow.xml too, because now the view complains, that no ${loginTicket} is found in the model.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use OAuth support for CAS, you need to upgrade to CAS server **3.5.0** : https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/OAuth